# Trying to get a variable pagination to show me 3 different types of paginations

Tags: laravel, pagination, backend, laravel-5.7

Here is my Index:

```
<div class="page-sizer">
                <a class="page numbers" href="{{$references->pagination(10)}}">10</a>
                <a class="page numbers" href="{{$references->pagination(30)}}">30</a>
                <a class="page numbers" href="{{$references->pagination(100)}}">100</a>
                <button  href="qweqwe.qweqwe" class="btn btn-info float-right>112e1e1e1e"></button>
                </div>
```

My AdminreferenceController:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $references = Reference::orderBy('priority', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(50);

        return view('admin.reference.index', ['references' => $references]);

    }
```

and my Lengthawarepaginator:

```
public function __construct($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage = null, array $options = [])
    {
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }

        $this->total = $total;
        $this->perPage = $perPage;
        $this->lastPage = max((int) ceil($total / $perPage), 1);
        $this->path = $this->path !== '/' ? rtrim($this->path, '/') : $this->path;
        $this->currentPage = $this->setCurrentPage($currentPage, $this->pageName);
        $this->items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    }
```

. i currently get the error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::pagination does not exist. 
I want to have 3 buttons that show 3 different kinds of paginations like in stackoverflow in the search bar at the bottom.

Comment: I want to have 3 buttons that show 3 different kinds of paginations like in stackoverflow in the search bar at the bottom.  ?? where is it in stackoverflow

Comment: it's not `$references->pagination(10)` but `$references->paginate(10)`

Comment: As per the document https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination it should be  $references->links()

Comment: @Shibon if u search on stackoverflow anything on the search bar on the bottom right you will find a pagination of 3 different integers.

Comment: Have you tried my last comment

Comment: i have currently changed the pagination completly. i wrote a url with '/x/y/perpage/10,/x/y/perpage/30,/x/y/perpage/100'.i made a new route for it 'route::('/x/perpage/{count})' and changed my AdminReferenceController to public function index($perpage=false){if(!perpage){$perpage=10;}references=REference::orderBy('priority','desc')->orderBy('id'.'desc')->paginate($perpage);

Comment: @Shibon yes and i got the error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling pagination in  collection try like this

first you need to include the DB class before class deceleration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Then change the query like this

```
$references = DB::table('reference')->orderBy('priority', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5o);
    return view('admin.reference.index', ['references' => $references]);
```

In you view you need to access like this

```
{{  $references->links() }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Answer (score 0):

i have currently changed the pagination completly. i wrote a url with

```
/x/y/perpage/10,
/x/y/perpage/30,
/x/y/perpage/100,
```

i made a new route for it

```
route::('/x/perpage/{count})'
```

and changed my AdminReferenceController to

```
public function index($perpage = false)
    {
        if(!$perpage) {
            $perpage = 10;
        }
        $references = Reference::orderBy('priority', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($perpage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get time to work this out. But I found you calling pagination() instead of paginate. See my suggetion

```
<div class="page-sizer">
            <a class="page numbers" href="{{$references->paginate(10)}}">10</a>
            <a class="page numbers" href="{{$references->paginate(30)}}">30</a>
            <a class="page numbers" href="{{$references->paginate(100)}}">100</a>
            <button  href="qweqwe.qweqwe" class="btn btn-info float-right>112e1e1e1e"></button>
            </div>
```

Here I removed the paginate from index() and returns collection.

```
 public function index()
{
    $references = Reference::orderBy('priority', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc');

    return view('admin.reference.index', ['references' => $references]);

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: when i use your code i get the following error. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::currentPage(). but yeah it seems i called it wrong. it still didnt work so i guess ill go with my answer, although it is a bit saddening that i couldnt make it work. but thank you for your help nonetheless